# Missing values don't let me calculate trends in the modifiedmk package in R

Tags: r, trend

I am trying to calculate the **MannKendall trend test** with the **bcpw function**. Because of my **missing values** I am not able to obtain my results so I used the **remove_missing function** to eliminate non finite numbers and to remove columns with NA; nevertheless the bcpw function doesn't run. To set recreate the problem I will use the following example:

```
df <- data.frame(
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                      Season = c("Summer 1996",
                                 "Winter 1996-1997","Summer 1997","Winter 1997-1998",
                                 "Summer 1998","Winter 1998-1999","Summer 1999",
                                 "Winter 1999-2000","Summer 2000",
                                 "Winter 2000-2001","Summer 2001","Winter 2001-2002"),
                     Germany = c(NA,33.8,65.5,
                                 26.4,30.9,39.8,23.7,37.7,35.7,39.5,37.5,29.3),
                  Luxembourg = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
                                 NA,NA,16.5,33.3,35.4,27,25.5),
                      France = c(26.7,23.7,42.3,
                                 32.9,27.9,19.1,38.7,15,60.2,35.4,26.7,23.7),
                       Spain = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
                                 NA,NA,16.73,41.81,31.91,27.25,29.75))

remove_missing(df, na.rm = TRUE, vars = names(df), name = "", finite = TRUE)

library(modifiedmk)
df_results <-lapply(df[-1], bcpw)
```

And I get the following error
[image: error]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `remove_missing` function is part of which package?

Comment: you need to assign the output of `remove_missing` function to some variable and then use it in `lapply`. Something like: `df <- remove_missing(df)`

Comment: when I assign the output It eliminates all my rows, including those that do have data. `remove_missing` is from `ggplot2` package.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that issue is caused by `finite` argument. When it encounters a character column it drops everything. It is reported as an [issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4284) on tidyverse repo.

The function works fine without the argument i.e. `finite=FALSE`, even when you have `NaN`.

```r
df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  Season = c("Summer 1996",
             "Winter 1996-1997","Summer 1997","Winter 1997-1998",
             "Summer 1998","Winter 1998-1999","Summer 1999",
             "Winter 1999-2000","Summer 2000",
             "Winter 2000-2001","Summer 2001","Winter 2001-2002"),
  Germany = c(NA,33.8,65.5,
              26.4,30.9,39.8,23.7,37.7,35.7,39.5,37.5,29.3),
  Luxembourg = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
                 NA,NA,16.5,33.3,35.4,27,25.5),
  France = c(26.7,23.7,42.3,
             32.9,27.9,19.1,38.7,15,60.2,35.4,26.7,23.7),
  Spain = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
            NA,NA,16.73,41.81,31.91,27.25,29.75))

df2 = ggplot2::remove_missing(df)
#> Warning: Removed 7 rows containing missing values.

df3 = ggplot2::remove_missing(df, na.rm = TRUE, vars=names(df), name = "", finite=TRUE)

df2
#>              Season Germany Luxembourg France Spain
#> 8  Winter 1999-2000    37.7       16.5   15.0 16.73
#> 9       Summer 2000    35.7       33.3   60.2 41.81
#> 10 Winter 2000-2001    39.5       35.4   35.4 31.91
#> 11      Summer 2001    37.5       27.0   26.7 27.25
#> 12 Winter 2001-2002    29.3       25.5   23.7 29.75

df3
#> [1] Season     Germany    Luxembourg France     Spain     
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

You could also try the function `complete.cases` from base R, which also handles both `NA` and `NaN`.

```r
df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = T,
  Season = c("Summer 1996",
             "Winter 1996-1997","Summer 1997","Winter 1997-1998",
             "Summer 1998","Winter 1998-1999","Summer 1999",
             "Winter 1999-2000","Summer 2000",
             "Winter 2000-2001","Summer 2001","Winter 2001-2002"),
  Germany = c(NA,33.8,65.5,
              26.4,30.9,39.8,23.7,37.7,35.7,39.5,37.5,29.3),
  Luxembourg = c(NaN,NaN,NA,NA,NA,
                 NA,NA,16.5,33.3,35.4,27,25.5),
  France = c(26.7,23.7,42.3,
             32.9,27.9,19.1,38.7,15,60.2,35.4,26.7,23.7),
  Spain = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
            NA,NA,16.73,41.81,31.91,27.25,29.75))


df[complete.cases(df), ]
#>              Season Germany Luxembourg France Spain
#> 8  Winter 1999-2000    37.7       16.5   15.0 16.73
#> 9       Summer 2000    35.7       33.3   60.2 41.81
#> 10 Winter 2000-2001    39.5       35.4   35.4 31.91
#> 11      Summer 2001    37.5       27.0   26.7 27.25
#> 12 Winter 2001-2002    29.3       25.5   23.7 29.75
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Tidyverse also have a function:

```r
df %>% tidyr::drop_na()
```